# How to add jquery file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I have 5 js files.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

and i want to number 3 & 4 js file add my template using jquery.

My template js like

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
```

and i want to call a function inside custom js which will add number 3 & 4 js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery.getScript

```
$.getScript("assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( "owl.carousel loaded." );
});
$.getScript("assets/js/jquery.lazy.min.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( "jquery.laz loaded." );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the native code.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js";
$("head").append( script ); 
script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "assets/js/jquery.lazy.min.js";
$("head").append( script );
```